# Pandas how to groupby multiple columns with regex

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

The following is a representation of the data set I have and I want to group it by StudentId and Exam Year. As the original data contains the full date, I need to filter it out just based on the year.

Yes, I can modify the ExamDate column just to have the year or extract the year into a new column but is there are 'groupby', 'multiindex' or similar magic that would allow me to do it without introducing a new column or modifying the original data?

```
data = { 'ExamDate' : ['11/20/2019', '11/20/2019', '05/10/2019', '05/01/2020', '05/01/2020', '05/10/2019'],
     'StudentId' : [45, 44, 45, 46, 45, 44],
     'Grade' : [ 70, 65, 90, 67, 81, 61]
   }

grouped=df.groupby(['ExamDate', 'StudentId'])

for grp, frame in grouped:
    #print(grp)
    print(frame)
```

The current output is as below

```
     ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
4  05/01/2020         45     81
     ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
3  05/01/2020         46     67
     ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
5  05/10/2019         44     61
     ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
2  05/10/2019         45     90
     ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
1  11/20/2019         44     65
     ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
0  11/20/2019         45     70
```

And the expected output is something like this

```
  ExamYear  StudentId  Grade
1     2019         44     65
5     2019         44     61
  ExamYear  StudentId  Grade
0     2019         45     70
2     2019         45     90
  ExamYear  StudentId  Grade
4     2020         45     81
  ExamYear  StudentId  Grade
3     2020         46     67
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity, I've updated with the current and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['ExamDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ExamDate)
groups = df.groupby([df['ExamDate'].dt.year, 'StudentId'])
for grp, frame in groups:
    print(frame)
```

---

```
    ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
1 2019-11-20         44     65
5 2019-05-10         44     61
    ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
0 2019-11-20         45     70
2 2019-05-10         45     90
    ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
4 2020-05-01         45     81
    ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
3 2020-05-01         46     67
```

---

```
groups = df.groupby([df['ExamDate'].dt.year, 'StudentId'])
for grp, frame in groups:
    frame.loc[:,'ExamDate'] = frame['ExamDate'].dt.year
    print(frame)
```

---

```
   ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
1      2019         44     65
5      2019         44     61
   ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
0      2019         45     70
2      2019         45     90
   ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
4      2020         45     81
   ExamDate  StudentId  Grade
3      2020         46     67
```

Comment: I know very little python but my gut was there would be a proper way, thank you.